# Google chrome isn't allowing to automate joining a gmeet

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

I have made a simple program in Python using selenium to automatically navigate to a gmeet link set up disable camera/mic and click the join now button to enter the link. Here's the code below:

```
import string
import random
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time

opt = Options()
opt.add_argument("start-maximized")
opt.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
# Pass the argument 1 to allow and 2 to block

opt.add_experimental_option("prefs", { \
"profile.default_content_setting_values.media_stream_mic": 1,
"profile.default_content_setting_values.media_stream_camera": 1,
"profile.default_content_setting_values.geolocation": 1,
"profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications": 1
})
opt.add_experimental_option("useAutomationExtension", False)



driver = webdriver.Chrome(options = opt,executable_path = "path_to\\chromedriver.exe")

driver.get("https://meet.google.com/yiz-fdaz-tre")
time.sleep(5)
current_tab = driver.window_handles[0]
driver.switch_to_window(current_tab)
camera = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="yDmH0d"]/c-wiz/div/div/div[9]/div[3]/div/div/div[4]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[4]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]')
camera.click()

mic = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="yDmH0d"]/c-wiz/div/div/div[9]/div[3]/div/div/div[4]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[4]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]')
mic.click()

join = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="yDmH0d"]/c-wiz/div/div/div[9]/div[3]/div/div/div[4]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]/span/span')
join.click()

#time.sleep(5)
driver.close()
```

but when I execute this script a different chrome window opens which shows *Chrome is being controlled by an automated test software* and meet doesn't allow me to join the meeting. I can't even join the meeting manually from that chrome window as to when I try to sign in it doesn't even allow me to sign in, However, if I click on google chrome and open a window afresh, everything works just as fine. The problem seems to occur when my code tries to open/create a new instance of Chrome. I tried downgrading to version 93 but it didn't help. Also removing the `driver.close()` statement was of little use.
Is there any way to automate this process, am I doing something wrong in my code?

Answer (score 1):

Google doesn't like automated browsers. Use "Undetected Chromedriver" instead of webdriver.

Install via pip: `pip install undetected_chromedriver`

Then replace `webdriver` with `undetected_chromedriver` (or just import UC as
webdriver to make it easier). I'm not quite sure if it still needs a webdriver path as it is installed using pip, however here is an adapted version of your script (also using `driver.find_element(By.*, STRING)`:

```py
import string
import random
import undetected_chromedriver as webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

opt = Options()
opt.add_argument("start-maximized")
opt.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
# Pass the argument 1 to allow and 2 to block

opt.add_experimental_option("prefs", { \
"profile.default_content_setting_values.media_stream_mic": 1,
"profile.default_content_setting_values.media_stream_camera": 1,
"profile.default_content_setting_values.geolocation": 1,
"profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications": 1
})

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options = opt)

driver.get("https://meet.google.com/yiz-fdaz-tre")
time.sleep(5)
current_tab = driver.window_handles[0]
driver.switch_to_window(current_tab)
camera = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="yDmH0d"]/c-wiz/div/div/div[9]/div[3]/div/div/div[4]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[4]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]')
camera.click()

mic = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="yDmH0d"]/c-wiz/div/div/div[9]/div[3]/div/div/div[4]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[4]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]')
mic.click()

join = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="yDmH0d"]/c-wiz/div/div/div[9]/div[3]/div/div/div[4]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]/span/span')
join.click()

#time.sleep(5)
driver.close()
```

Not sure if this helps or not, but it's worked for me so far.

Comment: Thanks for your response but it doesn't work!!!